# Find all functions $f :\mathbb{N_0} \to \mathbb{N_0}$ such that $f(f(n)) = n + k$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$ and $k$ is a positive integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, contest-math, functional-equations

### Problem

Let $k$ be a positive integer. Find all functions $f :\mathbb{N_0} \to \mathbb{N_0}$ such that
$$f(f(n)) = n + k$$
for any $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$.

### My approach

I tried substitution. Here is what I got:
$$f(f(n+1))-f(f(n))=1 \tag{1}$$
$$f(n+k)=f(f(f(n)))=f(n)+k \tag{2}$$
However, I don't know how to use them to proceed further.
As suggested in the comments, here is what I got for $k=1$ and $k=2$.
For $k=1$,
Using $(2)$ we have $$f(n+1)=f(n)+1$$
Now let $f(0)=c$ such that $c \in \mathbb{N_0}$. Then, we have $f(n)=n+c$. Then $$f(f(n))=n+2c=n+1$$
which is a contradiction and this leads there is no solution for $k=1$.
For $k=2$, similar works lead that $f(n)=n+1$ is the only solution.

---

So, I need a generalized solution to the problem.

Comment: (2) seems promising. Why not try $k=1$ or 2 if you can't do the general case yet?

Comment: @MatthewTowers $f(n)=n+1$ seems to be a solution for $k=2$. However, I am not sure if there is any solution for $k=1$.

Comment: If $k$ is even, $f(n)=n+k/2$ seems to be a solution.

Comment: Hint: (2) tells us that $ f(n)$ is completely determined by $ f( n \pmod{k})$. So, what can $ f(0), f(1), ... f(k)$ be? From here, (with a further argument) show that if $k $ is odd then no solution exists, and if $k$ is even, then what happens here? If stuck, try $k = 4$, and be creative with $f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: It's late, so I might have made an error here. However, I believe this is correct.)

Hint / Steps: (If you're stuck, show what you've tried.)

- OP showed that $f(n+ k) = f(n) + k$.
- Hence, the function is uniquely defined by $ f(0), f(1), \ldots f(k-1)$.

Let $ a_k$ denote $ a \mod{k}$.
Let $ [k] = \{0, 1, \ldots, k-1\}$.

- Show that if $ f(a_k ) = b_k$, then 1) $a_k \neq b_k$ and 2) $f(b_k) = a_k$. Hence, we can pair up these residues.
- Hence if $ k$ is odd, then there are no solutions.
- Show that if $ a, b \in [k] $ such that $f(a_k) = b_k$, then either $f(a) = b, f(b) = a+k$ or $f(a) = b+k, f(b) = a$.
- Hence, if $k$ is even, show that there are $\frac{ k!}{ (k/2)!}$ solutions. Describe all of them.